# node.js weather api socket hangup

Tags: node.js

I have node.js code that tries to fetch some weather JSON from the API at api.weather.gov.
My file structure is

```
weather.js
weatherServer.js
```

Here is `weather.js`:

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')

/**
 * current weather at a location
 * @param {*} latitude 
 * @param {*} longtitude 
 * @param {*} resultCallback callback function
 */
exports.current = (latitude, longtitude, resultCallback) => {
    const options = {
        hostname: 'api.weather.gov',
        path: `/points/${latitude},${longtitude}`,
        method: 'GET',
    }

    const request = https.request(options, response => {
        console.log('got response')

        let data = ''
        response.on('data', chunk => {
            data += chunk
        })
        response.on('end', () => {
            console.log(data)
        })
    })

    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`Request error: ${err}`)
    })
}
```

Here is `weatherServer.js`:

```
const weather = require('./weather')

weather.current(39.7456, -97.0892, null)
```

I get this log on my terminal:

```
Request error: Error: socket hang up
```

But when I visit the API website, I can see the JSON response displayed on the browser.
For example, I type `https://api.weather.gov/points/39.7456,-97.0892` on my browser and I do see the response JSON.

Any clarification on this would be appreciated.